# Why is my SQL Server database returning multiple values for this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDITED: I fixed the mis-matched query and data

I'm using Visual Basic to query a SQL Server database to try to make a program to generate a report for a client. They already have report generating software, but it doesn't do what they want. I'm trying to join data from 3 different tables in one query, and I've come up with the following (I've removed the irrelevant fields from the query):

```
SELECT lineitem.lineitemid,
       lineitem.cost,
       lineitem.sale,
       partitem.partitemid,
       partitem.lineitemid,
       partitem.quantity,
       partitem.partid,
       part.partid,
       part.cost,
       part.description,
       inventorytransaction.partid,
       inventorytransaction.cost,
       inventorytransaction.orderdate
FROM   sm.lineitem  
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN sm.partitem 
         ON partitem.lineitemid = lineitem.lineitemid 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN sm.part
         ON partitem.partid = part.partid
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN sm.inventorytransaction
         ON part.partid = inventorytransaction.partid
WHERE  lineitem.lineitemid > 62421 AND lineitem.lineitemid < 62442
```

The problem is that it returns 100+ values for the same id. Here's a sample from the actual query:

```
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   12/10/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   10/20/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   9/1/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   8/26/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   8/13/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   7/2/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   6/4/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   5/20/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   4/29/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   3/19/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   2/25/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   1/29/2010 19:00
62422   2.23    4.99    31964   1   2   OIL FILTER  2   12/31/2009 19:00
```

If I run `SELECT * from lineitem` it returns unique values:

```
362440  25.44   -318715 -318715
362441  0   -318716 -318716
362442  15.96   -318717 -318717
362443  0   -318718 -318718
362444  13.5    -318719 -318719
362445  1.65    -318720 -318720
362446  0   -318721 -318721
362447  0   -318722 -318722
362448  0   -318723 -318723
362449  0   -318724 -318724
```

What's wrong? What other information do you need to answer the question?

I've tried several variations of `JOIN` to no avail. `UNION` won't work because of conflicting data types and I need info that is unique to specific tables.

Side note: I didn't design the database, If I had, I wouldn't need to query 3 different tables this way to do what they want.

Comment: Because there's more than one `inventorytransaction` row that matches some line items?

Comment: We need to know the relationships between the tables (1:1, 1:m, ...). Probably, you have a 1:n in there that you did not expect. This can lead to duplication and combinatorial explosion.

Comment: Have a closer at what's a right outer join, maybe ?

Comment: That can't be a sample from your query.  The third column is not matching the first column, and both those should be line item ID.

Comment: It looks like the last column with the date is what is making the records unique.  If you can drop that column, you'd probably get better results.

Comment: It's a sample from the actual query. I abbreviated the query, and then realized I should post the actual one, so I edited the question and put the actual query at the bottom.

Comment: I like the idea of dropping the date, except for the fact that that's required for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: 1. stop lying to us; your example query does not match your sample output.  2. Pay attention; the last column of your sample output clearly has a different value for each row.  This probably indicates that one of the joins that you don't want us to see has a multi row match (i.e. is part of a 1-to-n relationship). 3. read something about outer joins.

Comment: So which date do you *need*? The most recent one? The earliest one? One selected based on some other criteria?

Comment: 1. I don't appreciate being called a lair. I posted the full query at the bottom because I knew the abbreviated query would cause issues. 2 I'll look at the possibility of a 1-to-n relationship.

Comment: From what I can see, I would pay closer attention to the join on `sm.inventorytransaction`. That table has an `orderdate` field, but you are joining just any time a `partid` matches. Is there also some way to limit that join by a specific order, like possibly from `sm.lineitem`?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the tables in visual studio. I believe I've created the query in the only possible way given what I need to do.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggqak0amuqy8z64/Screenshot%202014-05-14%2010.33.30.png

Comment: `LineItem` doesn't contain a `PurchaseOrderId` field by chance, does it?

Comment: I must say that I do not understand your use of RIGHT JOIN. I always found them to be very confusing.; Could you describe in words what the query is supposed to do? What is each row supposed to represent?

Comment: The query is supposed to return the the date, cost, id info and description for parts listed in a database. The RIGHT JOIN just happened to be where I was in my iterations when I came for help.

The end goal is to add the cost of parts to this report...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrsyw3dg3kjdjjz/reportToCopy.tiff

Comment: I don't think you really need right outer joins either. Joins have specific meaning and just randomly changing them is a bad choice. Of course the way you used your where clause changed them all to inner joins anyway. (BTW this isformation is best stored in multiple tables, so get over your hatred of joins and learn to use them correctly and correctly design a database.)

Comment: So you need one row per invoice?

Comment: What do you recommend? I don't necessarily hate JOINS, I just don't like the fact that these tables don't have a a way to easily do what I want. I can think of other ways to do this that would be easier and still use multiple tables. For instance, since we're dealing with car parts here they could have used the VIN as an identifier throughout the database, that way I could do `SELECT vin, blah, blag, blog FROM tablex JOIN tabley ON tablex.vin=tabley.vin`.

Comment: @usr yea, something like that.

Comment: it looks like the duplicate is from `inventorytransaction.orderdate` so you must have more than 1 `inventorytransaction` for each `partid`. You need to somehow aggregate these or be more selective to get a unique record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I talked to a co-worker and we figured it out. It's a case of having a 1-to-n relationship as a number of you suggested. I guess I didn't understand the database. It turns out that each LineItemId is related to a transaction that may have multiple Parts associated with it. The way I ended up narrowing it down is by date. The final query is the same as the one in the question but with `WHERE  inventorytransaction.orderdate > 'some-date' AND < 'some-other-date'` tacked on to the end. I also dropped the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` in favor of a normal `JOIN.` Now I have to wrap all this in a usable interface and ship it off to the customer :)